# Access BLE data using Flutter and Store it in a SQFlite Database

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy, flutter-dependencies, sqflite

Hey guys i'm Really Confused in Accessing the BLE data using Flutter_Blue Library,Even-though going through the Example Project of Flutter_Blue

https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue/archive/master.zip

Its hard to understand can anyone please give me a solution for it,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to scan for other BLE devices, connect to them, exchange data? I see that that readme of this repo https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue is really well written.

Comment: Actually I want to scan the BLE device from the mobile and access those BLE data by retriving and store it in a local database using SQFlite.Thanks TroungSinh

Comment: Exactly I need a walkthrough for this code https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue/archive/master.zip can anybody help me